# Deserialize Jackson object with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson, json-ld

Recently I have used Jackson combined with Spring MVC for serializing domain objects.
In order to reduce cyclic references I have used `@JsonIdentityInfo` like this:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@modId")
public class Modulo implements Serializable {
...
}
```

What I am doing now is to receive those objects as JSON.
I would like to deserialize the objects and access to them but I only can do that with first reference to each object. I cannot access to next references to same object. Mainly I don't know how to do that.

What I want to do is to create an HTML table with objects received.
I would do this with Javascript or jQuery.
Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Jackson 2.0+ is implementing a bit of [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld-syntax/) here. Maybe [jsonld.js](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js#readme) is what you need?

Comment: Let me check it. Due I am working on other stuff it will take a while. Thanks for references.

Comment: @pkmorken I am reading JSON-LD specification and I have some doubts. 1) Can I use JSON-LD keeping my JSON generator (Jackson+Spring MVC) unalterable or should I use Node.js or any other extra backend component? 2) If I keep my configuration, should I include the `@context` to my JSON and `jsonld.js` will take care of this in front-end side? Thanks